# Hive select query - doesn't print bad records

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table 'Order_Header_frm_spark_6'. I would like to select only those records that are in mm/dd/yyyy format and print those records as 'rejected', else 'not_rejected'. But when I use the query given below, I see all the records as not_rejected. [Input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mrb9.png). Output of hive query is given below.

Query :
[select * ,case when Order_Date = '%/%' then 'Reject' else 'not_rejected' END from Order_Header_frm_spark_6;]

[Hive Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIrEi.png)

Comment: you can split the line by '|' and take the third element from it.

Comment: where exactly? could you please help me doing that. I am new to spark and have been trying for hours to get this working

Comment: I tried to split the line on '|' , how ever i want to print/ raise a flag there as "rejected" if the date is in mm/dd/yyyy format. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with like operator

select * ,case when Order_Date like '%/%' then 'Reject' else 'not_rejected' END from Order_Header_frm_spark_6;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select * ,case when order like '**/**/____' then 'Reject' else 'not_rejected' END from Order_Header_frm_spark_6;

See comment for correct query.
For Hive

Comment: select * ,case when order like '__/__/____' then 'Reject' else 'not_rejected' END from Order_Header_frm_spark_6;